# Working out how many hours worked after a certain time

Tags: c#, datetime, duration

I am working on some custom rules in a time managment system and need to know how many hours in a shift have been before a certain time (19:00pm) and how many hours after. Shifts can start in the evening and finish in the morning so need to take that into account.

So far I have the below (this is just a snippet for one day) however it seems very clumsy and eloborate what I have written, can't help but feel I am missing a simpler solution, anyone have any ideas?

```
        DateTime cutOffTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 19, 00, 00);
        string cutOffTimeOfDay = GetTimeOfDayFromDateTime(cutOffTime);

        double baseMondayHours = 10.00;
        baseMondayHours = (baseMondayHours - 0.5);

        if (GetTimeOfDayOnlyFromDateTime(monday.ShiftStart.Value) == "AM" && GetTimeOfDayOnlyFromDateTime(monday.ShiftEnd.Value) == "PM"
            && monday.ShiftEnd.Value.TimeOfDay < cutOffTime.TimeOfDay)
        {
            postCutOffMondayHours = 0;
            baseMondayHours = monday.HoursWorked.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            string endTimeOfDay = GetTimeOfDayFromDateTime(monday.ShiftEnd.Value);
            double hoursAfterCutOff = GetDuration(cutOffTimeOfDay, endTimeOfDay);

            postCutOffMondayHours = hoursAfterCutOff;
            baseMondayHours = (baseMondayHours - hoursAfterCutOff);
        }

    public static string GetTimeOfDayFromDateTime(DateTime d)
    {
        return d.ToString("HH:mm") + " " + d.ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static string GetTimeOfDayOnlyFromDateTime(DateTime d)
    {
        return d.ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();
    }

        public static double GetDuration(string startTime, string endTime)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startTime);
            DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(endTime);
            if (start > end)
                end = end.AddDays(1);

            TimeSpan duration = end.Subtract(start);

            return duration.TotalHours;
        }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have put it on codereview, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm  not sure if I'm missing something here, but isn't the built-in operator- of `DateTime` exactly what you're looking for? It returns the `TimeSpan` between the 2 `DateTime`, and if you can guarantee shiftStart < cutoffDateTime < shiftEnd, then you can get the hours worked by just using the `TotalHours` of `TimeSpan` (but adding that check is just an additional small `if`)

```
var shiftStart = new DateTime(2020, 6, 2, 17, 0, 0);
var shiftEnd = new DateTime(2020, 6, 3, 6, 30, 0);
var cutoffDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 6, 2, 19, 0, 0);

var hoursWorkedBefore = (cutoffDateTime - shiftStart).TotalHours;
var hoursWorkedAfter = (shiftEnd - cutoffDateTime).TotalHours;
```